# Remote Validation in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am performing Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC3,but its not working means it not calling the action as I am seeing in Chrome java script Console.Here is my Code:
Model:

```
public class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        [Remote("GenreNameExist","Genre",ErrorMessage="Genre name already Exists!!!")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GenreNameExist(Genre genre) 
        {
             var gen = db.Genres.Where(x=>x.Name==genre.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (gen == null)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else {

                return Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

and View:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Name)
    </div>
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
var gen = db.Genres.Where(x=>x.Name==Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

so it will execute.

In the controller pass the class `Genre` so it maps to that class and then add `if(ModelState.IsValid)` so it'll perform validation against that class. Or add a ViewModel class.

Update:

Do you have the scripts in the right order?

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: How does the controller look like that shows the page + postback? And do they render the data- attributes in the textboxes and labels on the page?

Comment: <input data-val="true" data-val-remote="Genre name already Exists!!!" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name" data-val-remote-url="/Admin/Genre/GenreNameExist" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">


<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

Comment: And how does the action for the save/create method look?

Comment: And have you enabled clientside validation in webconfig?

Comment: <script src="@Url.Action("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Action("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Action("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Genre genre) 
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Genres.Add(genre);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("","");
            }
            return View();
        }

Comment: yes i have enabled that also in web.config.. <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

Comment: Add [Required] to Name and see if that triggers it

Comment: You have a @using(Html.BeginForm()) around the form?

Comment: You might have another web.config in the Views folder, so it might be ambigious

Comment: yes...but that is required when we want to post the data on button click here we want on ajax call not on submission of the form.am i right?but still i have kept it in @using(Html.BeginForm()) because i am saving the data as well

Comment: Might work with the Ajax.BeginForm like this: @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div-outside-form-id" }))

Comment: Do you have nested forms on the page?